# Creating own angularjs $q promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

This example is attempting to make synchronous code asynchronous.  All examples I found were doing the opposite except the main first example at docs.angularjs.org .. $q below.

The doc lists a $q constructor which I am attempting to use.  Unfortunately, the jsfiddle Angular libraries 1.1.1 and 1.2.1 provide a $q object (not a function) as in this example.  Instead, I'll have to provide my example and hope that someone will see the bug.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

I need to see "this does not happen!" line to execute.

```
f = function(name) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log "this does not happen!"
        resolve('great')
    });
}


f(name).then(function(result) {
  console.log 'result', result
}, function(error) {
  console.log 'error', error
});
```

Instead of logging "this does not happen!" followed by "great", I actually see the function passed to $q logged::

```
    result function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log "this does not happen!"
        resolve('great')
    }
```

Can someone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. I don't really think it's appropriate that the angular docs show that code with this line hidden right above it:

> While the constructor-style use is supported, not all of the
>   supporting methods from ES6 Harmony promises are available yet.

It causes much confusion, as you an see.

Use the constructor method (like Zipper posted)

```
var dfd = $q.defer();
```

and then you can do the following:

```
dfd.reject('some value');
dfd.resolve('some value');
```

Answer (score 5):

A little hard to see exactly what you're attempting, but here is some code we use that might help.

```
f = function(someValue){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    doSomethingAsync(someValue, function(result){ return deferred.resolve(result)});
    return deferred.promise;
}

f("foo").then(function() {alert("I was called after the async thing happened")})
```

Comment: I don't have a luxury of having a doSomethingAsync method with a call back.  Looks like it can not be done with the typical $q.defer() method.  One example is to wrap file IO the mimics the localstorage in the browser.  The nodejs side will use a file synchronous side to mimic the real standard.  That is synchronous.